# How to get device size (mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I try to draw a circle in the middle of the device browsers width and height. But the canvas element disturb. The circle become draw in the middle of the devices width and height, if I make the canvas big enough, but the canvas size should fit in the device size.

Is there any way to fit the canvas width and height the device width and height?

thats the solution:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
    /* Remove padding and margin */
    * { 
      margin:0; 
      padding:0; 
    } 

    html, body, .myCanvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" class="myCanvas"/>
    <script>

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;

      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = width / 2;
      var centerY = height / 2;
      var radius = 70;


      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#FF3300';
      context.stroke();

      console.log("width: " + width);
      console.log("height: " + height);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css % size

HTML:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" class="myCanvas"/>
```

CSS:

```
/* Remove padding and margin */
* { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
} 

html, body, .myCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Edit**:

Get the width/height of your canvas instead of the window.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style>
    /* Remove padding and margin */
    * { 
      margin:0; 
      padding:0; 
    } 

    html, body, .myCanvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    } 
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" class="myCanvas"/>
    <script>

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var width = canvas.width;
      var height = canvas.height;

      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var centerX = width / 2;
      var centerY = height / 2;
      var radius = 70;


      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#FF3300';
      context.stroke();

      console.log("width: " + width);
      console.log("height: " + height);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `height: 100%` is almost always problematic: 100% of *what*?

Comment: This will not resize the canvas but stretch it.

Comment: 100% of the body in this case.

Comment: it would however work in OP's example, as the elements above the canvas are Body and HTML.

Comment: @R3tep, not really. Technically it is "100% of the height of the container", but that implies the container has a fixed height. Otherwise, the rendering engine cannot apply a definitive height since a page is basically unbounded in the vertical direction. In this specific case I believe that would reliably work only if the `<body>` element (and possibly the `<html>` element) are also styled with `height: 100%`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it would work without the height set to 100%, providing that is is not set to anything

Comment: what about 'height: 100vh'

Comment: @Liam, have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n011m4h/). At least on Firefox, you will notice the blue `<canvas>` (and actually the `<body>` itself) does not fill the available vertical area unless you uncomment the `height` rules on both the `<body>` and the `<html>` elements (and even then it overshoots by a few pixels, possibly a margin issue).

Comment: vh unit is equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block. It's the same in this case?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I updated my post. Indeed, there is a `padding` and `margin` too.

Comment: With `window.innerWidth;` and `window.innerHeight;`

Comment: ok thank you, I edit my post but it wont work. Where is the mistake? :)

Comment: `height 100%;` => `height: 100%;` You forgot ":"

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your code, right after getting the canvas:

```
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

You can also remove `width` and `height` attributes from the html part

Comment: I paste it under var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'); and it works, but on the right side and the bottom of the window came a scrollable bar.... How can I fit it?